# Reset prometheus metric if it was not reported for period of time in python

Tags: python, prometheus, prometheus-python-client

I have a python app with Gauge metric where I report latest value reported by some device. I want to create a mechanism that will reset the value to zero if the metric was not reported for more than 30 min. Is there a way to do it without keeping the map of last report times?
Is there a way to get the last report time from the metric object itself?

Comment: By "report time" do you mean last call of method `set` on the metric?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Gauge in prometheus_client only uses timestamp for changes of value internally, and only is [some of the multiprocess modes](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/master/prometheus_client/metrics.py#L415), without a way to extract it.

You can probably create your own wrapper class that will inherit `Gauge`, and will wrap method `set` (and all other methods that you need) with custom logic, that will track last changes and through callback return corrected value as you need.

---

On the other hand, you can rather easily achieve same behaviour in promql.
Query `metric * (changes(metric [30m]) > bool 0)` returns value of `metric` if it was changed in the last 30 minutes, and 0 otherwise.<sup>1</sup>

Here, function [`changes`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes) is used to track number of changes in metric over specified range. And comparison operator `>` is used with modifier [`bool`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) ir used to return result of 1 if expression is true, and 0 - otherwise.

<sup>1</sup> : This solution, being "implemented" fully on Prometheus' side can **not** differentiate between metric not being changed, or it being set to the same value over and over. Please take this into account when choosing a solution.

Comment: The second part wont work for me because of your latest remark. I need to zero the value that is not changing and is still being scraped. 
The first suggestion will work. I'll still leave the question open to make sure the there is no simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: @EduardGrinberg, to be clear, accepting an answer doesn't close question: it still can receive new answers. But I don't suggest you to accept **this** answer, as it has only general overview of how to solve task (and a workaround). Hopefully somebody more proficient in Python can provide an answer with proper code (or you'll do it once you implemented what you need)